# JS String literals

Tags: javascript

Why in first example we wrap everything inside () and in second example with string literals just one part

[image]

Comment: Because ` is not supported by old browsers. So there is two different options to achieve the same goal depending on the environment you are targeting

Comment: If I'm not missing something, the bracket in both of the examples are not needed. Sometimes is more readable though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parentheses are not required by JavaScript. These are just there to make the code more readable to the user (by grouping the conditions).